# Passing multiple arguments to Predicate<T>

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda

I am calling a filtering method that accepts parameter Predicate T

```
void MethodName(Predicate<T> param)
{
}

x.MethodName(x => x.SomeProperty == 10); // or
x.MethodName(delegate(MyClass x) {return x.SomeProperty == 10;});
```

The problem is that I need to be able to filter on several different values, and the number of values is unknow. Example with 3 values ouwld be

```
x.MethodName(x => x.SomeProperty == 10 || x => x.SomeProperty == 20); // or
x.MethodName(delegate(MyClass x) {return x.SomeProperty == 10 || x.SomeProperty == 20;});
```

Can I make it work with uknown number of possible values? This would be greate, but its not possilbe :)

```
x.MethodName(x => x.SomeProperty == {10, 20});
```

Comment: declare a list or array of `{10,20}` and then `x => list.Contains(x.SomeProperty)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.MethodName(x => new []{10, 20}.Contains(x.SomeProperty));
```

Comment: This will create a new array every time the predicate is called. If you declare the array outside of the lambda, the array will only be created when the lambda is declared.

Comment: The OP mentioned unknown number of items to compare to but did not mention anything about how many times this filter would be called. I assumed it's just once for a given set of values.

Comment: Yes, its one time only. Maybe what Gabe wanted to say is, everytime when x.SomePropety evalues to new value (during the filtering), it will recreate the array. Example, in a collection of 100 producsts, if I search the products of category 1. 3 and 5 it will create 100 times this array. I havent tested this though, its only my interpretation, since I will be creating an array outside the method anyway.

Thanks, it works great.